# Trigger Teamcity build only if user is a member of Github organisation

Tags: teamcity

Is there any way in Teamcity to trigger a build task only if a person who committed to a repository is a member of particular Github organisation ?

Comment: you can use GitHub Pull Requests and define the organization (Members of the same organisation), it's will trigger the build by for each PR only for your organisation

Comment: That is the correct answer: GitHub Pull Requests plugin let us select who will trigger the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use GitHub Pull Requests and define the organization (Members of the same organisation), it's will trigger the build by for each PR only for your organisation